# DateTimeField keeps saying invalid date/time

Tags: python, django, forms, date

I created a form that runs smoothly, but when I added in a DateTimeField, the form won't pass as valid anymore. I get the error that I inputted the wrong date/time; however, I have tried every date input format, and it still hasn't worked. I have a feeling the issue may lie in my form field for DateTimeField, but am unsure what the exact issue is. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None, related_name='lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson_instrument = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=instrument_list, blank=True)
    lesson_level = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=level_list, blank=True)
    lesson_length = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=length_list, blank=True)
    lesson_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    lesson_weekly = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lessons

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_lessons(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Lesson.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_lessons(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        for lesson in instance.lessons.all():
            lesson.save()
```

forms.py

```
class LessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lesson_instrument = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_length = forms.ChoiceField(choices=length_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'datetime-local'}))
    lesson_weekly = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('lesson_instrument', 'lesson_level', 'lesson_length', 'lesson_datetime', 'lesson_weekly')
```

views.py

```
def new_lesson(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LessonForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            lessons = form.save(commit=False)
            lessons.user = request.user
            lessons.save()
            messages.success(request,'Lesson successfully created')
            return redirect('/teacher/schedule')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Information entered was invalid')

    else:
        form = LessonForm()

    form = LessonForm()
    lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'form' : form, 'lessons': lessons}
    return render(request, 'teacher/new_lesson.html', context)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'type':'datetime-local' from your widget? DateTimeField renders by default as a TextField. What are you entering as input in the field that is throwing an error?

Comment: @Sam when I remove datetime-local, it becomes a text field with no indication of how to type the input, as opposed to a calendar I can choose from with datetime-local. As a result, I am unsure of how to type the proper format in the text field and I keep receiving an invalid date. Do you know how the types user input for datetimefield should be?

Comment: Got it. See answer below!

Comment: If this doesn't solve things, let me know what error you are getting when the form processes. That'll help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Check `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` in your settings file. If it's not specified, it'll default to the values shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS).

Then, add a `format=` argument to your `DateTimeInput` widget (see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput)) for more info on how to do this) and make sure that it aligns with one of the formats supported by your `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` setting.